# JMS messages being consumed from single server

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have a clustered web logic environment with 2 servers.
The source drops `JMS messages` in the queues of both the servers.
My service, however, is designed to consume these messages only at a particular time of the day when it is activated by a `"trigger.txt"` file which is picked up by a file adapter which then activates the `BPEL` to start consuming JMS messages.

However, the problem is, if the server 1 adapter picks up the `trigger.txt file`, then JMS messages from only server 1 queue are consumed, messages on the other server are left untouched and vice versa.

I want the messages to be consumed by both the servers.

Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a WLS JMS issue. 
So the solution will lie within your BPEL implementation and your solution of leaving the trigger.txt file behind. 
I am assuming you are removing the trigger.txt once its picked by a BPEL instance. 
You will have to change this logic to say include timestamp something like trigger.txt so each BPEL instance picks and marks internally that it has picked this particular file and does it process it again.
or create 2 files one for each server, but this will be messy if you add say an extra server lateron.

The other option is for WLS to redirect the JMS messages to the server which has an active consumer, this would however effect your ability to parallely process the JMS messages on both the servers.